# How to delete object which is connected to another model with FK. ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There is the error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ShoppingCartItems_ItemsTable_ItemId". The conflict occurred in database "RandDb", table "dbo.ShoppingCartItems", column 'ItemId'. The statement has been terminated.

**Item**

```
public class Item : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Photo")]
        public string ItemPhoto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Type")]
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Size")]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Material Type")]
        public string MaterialType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Designed For")]
        public string DesignedFor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**CartItem**

```
public class CartItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T item)
{
    _entity.Remove(item);
    return await SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return (await _db.SaveChangesAsync()) >= 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I want to do the following: so I have an admin page from where i make crud operations, i also have shopping cart where user can add items, so when any item is added in cart of any user, it doesn't delete, it throws the error which i mentioned above. so what can i do to remove shopping cart items, when admin deletes this item from admin page.

Comment: Hello, deleting related entities is a little tricky, you need to include related subEntities :
var item= context.CartItem .OrderBy(e => e.Name).Include(e => e.Item).First();
context.Remove(item);
context.SaveChanges();

You can also breack the link with war entity by  : 
var item= context.CartItem .OrderBy(e => e.Name).Include(e => e.Item).First();
item.Item = null;

Look at this page for more details 
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: this context is little bit confusing to me, i also checked the link you provided but i dont get it where this context is coming from

Comment: Hello, I think in your code the context is "_db " object

Answer (score 1):

Delete is getting tricky when you have foreign keys, So I don't recomend you to use a generic repository. you can try this code

```
var cartItems= _entity.Set<CartItem>().Where(i=> i.ItemId == item.Id).ToArray();

    if(cartItems!=null) 
          foreach(var cartItem in cartItems) cartItem.ItemId=null;

    _entity.Set<Item>().Remove(item);

    return await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: okay but if i add this code in repository it won't be good. i mean i have to add item and cartItems references and would it be best practice?

Comment: @SabaMinashvili The generic repository is the bad practice, since EF core has it and UoF (unity or work too) already.  So it will only improve your code.

Comment: oh okay. one more question, where should i implement this code, i mean if i implement it in repository deleteAsync method it won't be correct, but if i do that in controller, it doesn't make sense... so i am little confused

Comment: @SabaMinashvili I usually create the repository, one for each controller ( not generic repository). It is the best place to put this code. Ideally, an each controller action should have only 2 lines of code - get model or result from  a repository and return View. This it the best practice.

Comment: for this kind of result i used CQRS in project and had only 2 lines of code, but in case of repositories, its more. somehow can i see your project structure? i mean where are these repositories located, how do they communicate with each controller and etc? it would be easier for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[Required]` would force cascade delete

```
public class CartItem : BaseEntity
{
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Or using Fluent API you can configure `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` to cascade delete.

Comment: Wait i am confused, i want to delete item and also all related cartItems and do these codes above do that? i mean it seems that these codes do opposite. i dont want to  delete cartItem and related items to it, i want to delete item and all related cartItem to this item

Comment: i tried this code but unfortunatly it still doesn't work :(